# Webpack Dependency Management and Vue.js async component loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am trying to achieve Vue.js dynamic `async component` registration. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YZ5DwlLSt8) gave me code that works perfectly fine, but it loads all modules even if they are not used.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst'
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase'
// Require in a base component context
const requireComponent = require.context(
  '../components/base', false, /base-[\w-]+\.vue$/,
)
requireComponent.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  // Get component config
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName)
  // Get PascalCase name of component
  const componentName = upperFirst(
    camelCase(fileName.replace(/^\.\//,
      '').replace(/\.\w+$/,
      '')),
  )
  // Register component globally
  Vue.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig)
})
```

What I tried to achieve was to create async components instead. Like so

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst'
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase'
// Require in a base component context
const requireComponent = require.context(
  '../components/base', false, /base-[\w-]+\.vue$/,
)
requireComponent.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentPath = fileName.replace('./', '../components/base/');
  // Get PascalCase name of component
  const componentName = upperFirst(
    camelCase(fileName.replace(/^\.\//,
      '').replace(/\.\w+$/,
      '')),
  )
  // Register component globally
  Vue.component(componentName, () => import(componentPath))
})
```

If the case of the code above vue throws an error

```
vue.esm.js:591 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function () {
    return __webpack_require__("./lib lazy recursive")(componentPath);
  }
Reason: Error: Cannot find module '../components/base/base-button.vue'
```

If I manually write down `Vue.component('BaseButton', () => import('../components/base/base-button.vue'))`
it works without problem but when I try to do that dynamically it fails. Is it possible to do such `async component` registration if so how?

This doesn't work either:

```
const button = '../components/base/base-button.vue'
Vue.component('BaseButton', () => import(button))
```

only if I literally right the string into import function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import` cannot be used when the module path is fully dynamic. See the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-):

> Fully dynamic statements, such as `import(foo)`, will fail because webpack requires at least some file location information. This is because foo could potentially be any path to any file in your system or project. The `import()` must contain at least some information about where the module is located, so bundling can be limited to a specific directory or set of files.

You didn't specify the `mode` argument for `require.context` which defaults to "sync"; this means all modules matched will be loaded straight away. You want to use "lazy" which generates a lazy-loadable chunk for each module.

Untested, but I imagine it'll be something like this:

```js
const context = require.context('../components/base', false, /base-[\w-]+\.vue$/, 'lazy');

context.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentPath = fileName.replace('./', '../components/base/');

  // Get PascalCase name of component
  const componentName = upperFirst(
    camelCase(fileName.replace(/^\.\//,
      '').replace(/\.\w+$/,
      '')),
  );

  // Register component globally
  Vue.component(componentName, () => context(fileName));
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much thats what I was looking for.

Comment: `Vue.component(componentName, () => import(`../components/base/${fileName.replace('./', '')}`))` this also works